# Reuse existing open window or command prompt when launching .bat file

Tags: console, window, command-prompt

I'm trying to debug a Blender add-on by launching Blender from a `.bat` file. I've managed to keep the command prompt window open, to see information, by adding `cmd /k` at the bottom. This is the entire file contents:

```
C:\Dev\Apps\Blender280\blender.exe
cmd /k
```

But each time I launch the `.bat` file, a new command prompt window opens. Is it possible to launch the `.bat` into the same console? If possible, I would prefer to launch Blender from a shortcut or keyboard key - I think I remember it being possible to launch `bat` files with a shortcut, but still need to look it up.

Comment: Here are some options: `@"C:\Dev\Apps\Blender280\blender.exe"&Pause` and `@"%__AppDir__%cmd.exe" /K "C:\Dev\Apps\Blender280\blender.exe"`.

Comment: I'm still generating new console windows when I run the `bat` file with both of these. Do I need to run the `bat` a specific way? Thanks for the help!

Comment: How are you running the batch file? From a `cmd.exe` window? in which they'd both open the blender GUI and only the second option would open one additional cmd.exe window, (unless you were running the batch file via another cmd.exe instance).

Comment: From a windows shortcut that is assigned the keyboard shortcut `F6`. Since I haven't been able to figure out how to launch into the same window, I set up repeating Blender executions in the `bat` file with pauses in between each one that wait for key press. So after the first launch, I just press a key on the command window. It's not too bad this way.

Comment: I know literally nothing about `bat` files, other than that they are similar to `DOS` and Windows command prompt. If there is something obvious I'm missing, please let me know.